# Having problems with toolbar.deactivate() in ESRI's API

Tags: javascript, draw, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to create a button that on click will activate **`esri.toolbars.Draw.EXTENT`** and then when clicked again will deactivate the toolbar and return to normal map navigation.

What I have works on the first click, but it doesn't seem to deactivate the tool bar on second click.

Everything seems to work **except** **`toolbar.deactivate()`** doesn't seem to fire.

```
function initToolbar(map) {
            var currentvalue = document.getElementById('searchByExtent').value;
            var toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
            if (currentvalue == "Off"){
                document.getElementById("searchByExtent").value="On";
                toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.EXTENT);
                dojo.connect(toolbar, "onDrawEnd", selectStuff);
                //toolbar.deactivate();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("searchByExtent").value="Off";
                toolbar.deactivate();
            }
        }

<input type    = "button"
       id      = "searchByExtent"
       value   = "Off"
       onclick = "initToolbar(map);">
       Search by Extent
     </input>
```

Comment: have you tried putting a console.log in your } else { to confirm that its not firing? that would be a good start to debugging this

Answer (score 1):

You've got a Javascript scoping issue.

When you activate your toolbar, everything works nicely:

```
var toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
...
toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.EXTENT);
```

...and you have an active toolbar in a variable called `toolbar`....but that variable is local to the `initToolbar` function. That function exits, and the variable is lost. When you try to deactivate the toolbar, you call `initToolbar` again:

```
var toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map); // This is NOT the same toolbar!
...
toolbar.deactivate(); // Makes no sense, it's not active.
```

Instead, define `toolbar` outside the function so the reference is maintained:

```
var toolbar = null; // define it here

function initToolbar(map) {
        var currentvalue = document.getElementById('searchByExtent').value;
        if (currentvalue == "Off"){
            toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map); // Create the toolbar here

            document.getElementById("searchByExtent").value="On";
            toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.EXTENT);
            dojo.connect(toolbar, "onDrawEnd", selectStuff);
        } else if (toolbar) { // If your value is not "Off" and the toolbar exists, then we can kill it.
            document.getElementById("searchByExtent").value="Off";
            toolbar.deactivate();
        }
    }
```